# Android SlidingPaneLayout Left Pane width

Tags: android, android-layout, chat, slidingpanelayout

I have been working on an android app where i have to implement chat , for which I am working with a Master-Detail flow for the actual chat just like any chat app would have , I have been using AndroidSlidingPaneLayout .

The problem I am having is that it appears like the Google hangouts app, with the right pane slightly exposed , which i dont want , I want the left pane to cover the entire screen width. I have tried many different things but so far no help.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content_viewspl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/conversations_overview_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:divider="@color/black12"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/selected"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't want the hangover marked as red in picture on right, the left pane should span full width

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZh3J.png)

Comment: Did you solve your problem?